# Excel, ThisAddIn.vb: why is Application.SheetFollowHyperlink not called for =HYPERLINK()

Tags: vb.net, excel, ms-office

I'm trying to detect clicked hyperlinks in Excel. The Application.SheetFollowHyperlink Event [claims](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821956.aspx) that it will be called "when you click any hyperlink in Microsoft Excel."

However, although it does fire when a cell contains a url like `www.google.com`, it does not when the cell contains `=HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com", "google")`.

How do I detect clicks to the second type of hyperlink?

---

For example, a simple excel add in:

```
Public Class ThisAddIn

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Startup

    End Sub

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shutdown

    End Sub

    Private Sub Application_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Hyperlink) Handles Application.SheetFollowHyperlink
        MsgBox("Hyperlink Clicked")
    End Sub
```

A message box containing "Hyperlink Clicked" will appear when you click a cell containing `www.google.com` but not a cell containing `=HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com", "google")`.

Comment: Perhaps this will be somehow helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14423084/1953175

Comment: Thanks @PeterL. that does look like the same problem. So given that this looks like a bug/feature in excel, can anyone suggest a workaround?

Comment: From where I sit the only way to use `Application.SheetFollowHyperlink` is to convert `HYPERLINK` links to usual ones using the code similar to available via my above link.

Comment: @PeterL. So this is weird. I installed your macro, generated my hyperlinks (my vb.net add in generates inter-sheet hyperlinks), and `Application_SheetFollowHyperlink()` is called. Now I uninstall your macro, restart excel, reboot my machine, clean/rebuild my vb.net project, regenerate my hyperlinks, and 'Application_SheetFollowHyperlink' is STILL called. I don't get it. On a separate machine that has never had your macro installed, `Application_SheetFollowHyperlink` still doesn't work.

Comment: sorry pal, I'm not familiar with any other programming except MS Office VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have solved the issue, although I'm not sure why the following works while the code I used above doesn't:

```
Private HyperlinkFollower As Excel.DocEvents_FollowHyperlinkEventHandler

Private Sub CalledWhenHyperlinkClicked(ByVal Target As Excel.Hyperlink)
    Dim w As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Window = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow
    MsgBox("hyperlink clicked")
End Sub

EventDel_HyperlinkFollower = New Excel.DocEvents_FollowHyperlinkEventHandler(AddressOf CalledWhenHyperlinkClicked)

AddHandler worksheet.FollowHyperlink, EventDel_HyperlinkFollower
```