# VBA produced HYPERLINK formula doesn't actually create workable hyperlink

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vbscript, vba

I'm trying to generate a HYPERLINK formula via VBA but when I click on the resulting link I get an Excel error message "Cannot open the specific file." I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422003/vba-to-open-excel-hyperlink-does-not-work-when-hyperlink-generated-with-a-formul) but same results.

This is my code to generate the link.

```
wksUsersSheet.Range(COMMENTARY_COL & lngRowNow).FormulaR1C1 = 
"=HYPERLINK(" & Chr(34) & "[" & strThisBooksName & "]" & 
strFoundMatchWorksheetName & "!" & strFoundMatchAddress & Chr(34) & "," 
& Chr(34) & rngReturnedMatchingPart.Value & Chr(34) & ")"
```

The immediate window displays this:
`=HYPERLINK("[UPN_Template_Wip]AleksV!$I$4","2322 734 61009L")`

I've tried it with `.Formula` as well but the result is the same.

I'm using Excel 2007 in Windows 7.  Am I missing something here 'cause it's all looking fine, just not working fine.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the macro recorder to create a hyperlink on a blank test sheet, I got:

```
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        "Sheet1!A1", TextToDisplay:="HL Here"
```

Translating that to your specifics, I believe you should have:

```
wksUsersSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=wksUsersSheet.Cells(lngRowNow, Commentary_Col), _
       Address:="", _
       SubAddress:="[" & strThisBooksName & "]" & strFoundMatchWorksheetName & "!" & _
                   strFoundMatchAddress, _
       TextToDisplay:=rngReturnedMatchingPart.Value
```

**Based on your comment** try this:

Convert your `strFoundMatchAddress` to a row number & a column number, I'll call them `FoundMatchAddrRow` and `FoundMatchAddrCol`

```
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=HYPERLINK(" & Chr(34) & "[" & strThisBooksName & "]" & _
strFoundMatchWorksheetName & "!R[" & FoundMatchAddrRow & "]C[" &  _
FoundMatchAddrCol & "],""" &  _
rngReturnedMatchingPart.Value & """)"
```

Note the use of `""` generates a single `"` in your final string & reduces the concatenation and eliminates the need for `Chr(34)`. It's not required, but it does reduce the typing.

Comment: My macro recorder gave me this:  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=HYPERLINK(AleksV!R[-15]C[-8],""2322 734 61009L"")". I'll try your option.

Comment: My bad - you're using Excel _2007_. I'm running _2010_ - that's probably the difference. It may still work, though.

Comment: Your answer works minus the "[" & strThisBooksName & "]". It only needs the worksheet reference, not the book's. Thanks!

Comment: My edit-comments-window lapsed so I'm adding that the ".Hyperlinks.Add" answer worked.