# Adding hyperlinks to multiple cells spread across a worksheet

Tags: excel, hyperlink

In my spreadsheet, there are cells that correspond to a certain url and they are spread across the sheet, and because of that I cannot select a group of cells and add hyperlinks to every cell in one go. I've tried using the find function and ctrl+A to select all but when I right clicked a cell the hyperlink option is greyed out. I've tried manually selecting the cells with ctrl+click on each cell that I want to have the same hyperlink. Once again the hyperlink option is greyed out.

Is there a more effective way to accomplish my task without having to individually add hyperlink to each cell since I have at least 3 thousand cells and only 200 unique hyperlink?

Thanks

Comment: what you tired so for can u put that code

Comment: What do you mean code? To add a hyperlink to a cell, all you have to do is right click the cell, and go into the hyperlink option and fill in the rest. My issue is I can't select multiple cells that will have the same hyperlink  with the methods I have explained in my post

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called HYPERLINK so one way of doing it if you have a set of values in column A and a table of hyperlinks that go with them in columns J and K would be like this:-

```
=IFERROR(HYPERLINK(VLOOKUP(A2,J$2:K$4,2,FALSE)),"")
```

Comment: unfortunately that is not applicable. The hyperlink must in the same cell. and  the cells are spread unevenly across a rectangle of cells. If it was all in one column, I could have sorted the column and solved my issue by selecting a continuous range of cells and add a hyperlink to all of them

Comment: OK actually I suspected that might be the case. Certainly worth looking at this though - maybe you could find and replace then convert the cells to hyperlinks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595692/how-do-i-convert-a-column-of-text-urls-into-active-hyperlinks-in-excel