# Add clickable link column to the reported query in Mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to have an extra column that is linked to an order. I am exporting the report but it recognises the html as text. I export it as `OpenDocument Spreadsheet` or `CSV for MSExcel` but no chance.

```
SELECT o.order_id, oci.count_files, 
       CONCAT_WS(  '',  '<a href="http://domain.co.uk/orders/view/?id=', o.order_id,  '">', o.order_id,  '</a>' ) AS Order_Link
FROM torg.temp_orders AS o
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT obe_order_master_id, COUNT( id ) AS count_files
    FROM kronos.customer_instalments
    GROUP BY obe_order_master_id
) AS oci ON oci.obe_order_master_id = SUBSTRING( o.order_id, 4 ) 
WHERE o.verified =  'verified'
  AND oci.count_files > 1
```

Is there any way that after exporting the report the link can be clickable?

Comment: sure. My first help is to suggest you to provide us some code to work on. What have you done so far?

Comment: Sorry mate completely forgot

Comment: and the issue is?

Comment: Which program is the „it“ that recognizes the HTML as text?

Comment: Is there any way that after exporting the report the link can be clickable?

Comment: Clickable *in what program*?

Comment: Probably in chines. What do you mean which language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have researched about it it is not possible to do this because MySql returns the data as string.

```
SELECT o.order_id, oci.count_files
FROM torg.temp_orders AS o
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT obe_order_master_id, COUNT( id ) AS count_files
    FROM kronos.customer_instalments
    GROUP BY obe_order_master_id
    HAVING count(id) = 1
) AS oci ON oci.obe_order_master_id = SUBSTRING( o.order_id, 4 ) 
WHERE o.verified =  'verified'
  AND oci.count_files > 1
```

But there is a way round after exporting data to `OpenDocument Spreadsheet` on the new column to do this `=HYPERLINK("http://domain.co.uk/orders/view/?id="&A1,A1)`

[How do I convert a column of text URLs into active hyperlinks in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595692/how-do-i-convert-a-column-of-text-urls-into-active-hyperlinks-in-excel)

But then again there is an other problem with that when I click the link Excel checks the link and tries to wrap it up and then some how in stupied excel way it breaks the bloody link so I wasted all day on this for almost nothing.