# Show hyperlink to entire column

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a code in VBA which fetch data from API( API data stored in the database) and showed it in an excel sheet.

below is my code:

```
Sub Auto_Open()

    Dim sJSONString As String
    Dim vJSON As Variant
    Dim sState As String
    Dim vElement As Variant
    Dim sValue As String
    Dim aData()
    Dim aHeader()
    
    

    ' Retrieve JSON string
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "http://localhost:3030/node/express/get/apidata", False
        .Send
        sJSONString = .responseText
    End With
    ' Parse JSON
    JSON.Parse sJSONString, vJSON, sState
    If sState = "Error" Then MsgBox "Invalid JSON string": Exit Sub
    
    ' Output the entire table to the worksheet
    JSON.ToArray vJSON, aData, aHeader
    With Sheets(1)
        .Cells.Delete
        .Cells.WrapText = False
        OutputArray .Cells(3, 1), aHeader
        Output2DArray .Cells(4, 1), aData
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    
   
   ' for hyperlinks
'   Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
 '  Range("L2:L1048576").Select

'    ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:=I.Value, TextToDisplay:=I.Value
    
    ' Dim sh As Worksheet, I As Range, rng As Range
    'Set sh = ActiveSheet
    'With sh
     '   Set rng = .Range("L2:L" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row)
        
      '  For Each I In rng.Cells
       '     .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L2:L"), Address:=I.Value, SubAddress:=I.Value, TextToDisplay:=I.Value
        'Next
    'End With
    
    
    'auto refresh code
   
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:30:00"), "Auto_Open"

End Sub



Sub OutputArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With.Resize(1, UBound(aCells) - LBound(aCells) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Sub Output2DArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize( _
                UBound(aCells, 1) - LBound(aCells, 1) + 1, _
                UBound(aCells, 2) - LBound(aCells, 2) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Now I want to show " L " column data in hyperlink format whenever the user clicks on "L" column data file automatically downloaded.

I have used the below code but this code covert entire sheet data to hyperlink:

```
 'Converts each text hyperlink selected into a working hyperlink

    For Each xCell In the Selection
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=xCell, Address:=xCell.Formula
    Next xCell
```

Please help me, guys. Thanks

Comment: Please show the code what defines "the Selection". Can it be you have selected the whole sheet?

Comment: @Aldert I took help from below link 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595692/how-do-i-convert-a-column-of-text-urls-into-active-hyperlinks-in-excel